# Regex to match string count with wildcard

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm having a difficult time creating regex and javascript code to count occurrences of this pattern:

```
<tr><td align=right>*</td><td align=right>*</td><td><a href="*">*</a></td></tr>
```

where as * is wild.

How can I go about searching for that?

Comment: no, the entire string, where as each * is a wildcard (can be anything)

Comment: Putting regex aside for a moment, what are you actually trying to achieve? (Regex may not be the best way: certainly [it's not very good at parsing html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/615754).) Are you saying that you have html markup already in a string?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is count occurences of that entire pattern, you can try:

```
// basically, numMatches = myString.match(/regexhere/ig).length;
numMatches = mystring.match(/<tr><td align=right>[\s\S]*?<\/td><td align=right>[\s\S]*?<\/td><td><a href="[^"]+">[\s\S]*?</a><\/td><\/tr>/ig).length;
```

The regex is the string you have above, except:

- `*` turns into `[\s\S]*?`. Usually, I'd replace with `.*?` but in regex `.` matches everything *except* newline characters. So, if your string spans multiple lines, it won't match. The usual way to get around this is to use the "dotall" regex modifier that allows `.` to match newlines too, but javascript doesn't support this (?!). `[\s\S]` is an alternative in this case.
- escaped occurences of `/` in the regex as I'm using `/` as my regex delimiter for javascript.

Note -- if you want to match where the tags may be split over multiple lines, e.g.

```
<tr>
  <td align=right>randomstuffhere</td>
  <td><a href="http://somelink">someotherstuff</a></td>
</tr>
```

Then change the regex so there's a `\s*` between every tag, which will allow whitespace in between. i.e.:

```
numMatches = mystring.match(/<tr>\s*<td align=right>[\s\S]*?<\/td>\s*<td align=right>[\s\S]*?<\/td>\s*<td>\s*<a href="[^"]+">[\s\S]*?</a>\s*<\/td>\s*<\/tr>/ig).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fun with jQuery:

```
var $matches = $('td[align=right] ~ td[align=right] ~ td > a')

$matches.length // the number of matches
$matches.attr('href') // the value of the anchor's `href` attribute
$matches.parent().prev().text() // the preceding cell's text
$matches.parent().prev().prev().text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build on this, which will match on any tag contents:

```
(?:.*?\>([^\<\>]+)\<)
```

And this for matching the href:

```
href\s*=\s*(["']).*?\1
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery way (may not be efficient),

```
var count = 0;
$('td[align=right],a[href=*]').each(function(){
if($(this).html() == '*'){
count++;
}
})

console.log(count);
```